# How to Invoke struct with CFFI

Tags: python, c++, python-cffi, cffi

I am using a python file to invoke a C++ struct already translated via cffi. I am currently getting errors with my struct being not callable. How can I call this struct properly? Am I cdef-ing the struct in the cffi translator properly in the first place?

(simple_cffi_builder.py)

```py
import os
from cffi import FFI

ffibuilder = FFI()

basePath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filePath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(basePath, "..", "..", "build/bin/simple_bfs.cpp"))

runtimePath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(basePath, "..", "..", "src/runtime_lib"))
intrinsicsPath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(basePath, "..", "..", "src/runtime_lib/intrinsics.h"))

with open(filePath,'r') as f:
    ffibuilder.set_source("_simplebfs_cffi",
                          f.read(),
                          include_dirs=[runtimePath],
                          source_extension = ".cpp",
                          extra_compile_args = ["-std=c++11"]
)

ffibuilder.cdef(
    """
    struct run_bfs{};
    """
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ffibuilder.compile(verbose=True)
```

The struct that I am trying to invoke (_simplebfs_cffi.cpp):

```
struct run_bfs
{
  void operator() () 
  {
 lots of code stuff
  }
}
```

The code I am using to invoke the C++ code generated (run_simple_bfs_cffi_python.py):

```
import os
import _simplebfs_cffi
from cffi import FFI

ffi = FFI()

class run_bfs():
    def __init__(self):
        self.bfs = _simplebfs_cffi.ffi.new("struct run_bfs*", None)

    def __call__(self):
        (self.bfs)()

run_bfs()()
```

When I try to run the code above, I get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                       File "run_simple_bfs_cffi_python.py", line 18, in                                                                                run_bfs()()                                                                                                                          File "run_simple_bfs_cffi_python.py", line 15, in **call**                                                                               (self.bfs)()                                                                                                                       TypeError: cdata 'struct run_bfs *' is not callable